# Help connecting to Fiber HBA

Tags: partitioning, mount, iscsi

We have a fiber channel set up, and I'd like to connect to it (I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 btw).

I can see the wwpns that were delivered.  But I don't quite know what to do from here.  I can fdisk to the /dev drives, but once I try to create a filesystem on them via mkefs, I get an ioctl error.

Here is what I show:

systool -c fc_host -A "port_name" gives me

```
Class = "fc_host"

Class Device = "host5"
port_name           = "0x21000024ff274080"

Device = "host5"


Class Device = "host6"
port_name           = "0x21000024ff274081"

Device = "host6"


Class Device = "host7"
port_name           = "0x21000024ff27411a"

Device = "host7"


Class Device = "host8"
port_name           = "0x21000024ff27411b"

Device = "host8"
```

When I do an ls -ltra /dev/mapper, I see

```
crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 May 12 14:52 control
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 May 12 17:37 360060e80042b570000002b5700000402 -> ../dm-2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 May 12 17:37 360060e80042b570000002b5700000400p1 -> ../dm-8
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 May 12 17:37 360060e80042b570000002b5700000400 -> ../dm-5
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 May 12 17:37 360060e80042b570000002b5700000403 -> ../dm-4
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 May 12 17:37 360060e80042b570000002b5700000400-part1 -> ../dm-6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 May 12 17:37 360060e80042b570000002b5700000404 -> ../dm-1
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 May 12 17:37 360060e80042b570000002b5700000401 -> ../dm-3
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     260 May 12 17:37 .
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 May 12 17:37 360060e80042b570000002b5700000405p1 -> ../dm-9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 May 12 17:37 360060e80042b570000002b5700000405 -> ../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7 May 12 17:37 360060e80042b570000002b5700000405-part1 -> ../dm-7
```

ls /sys/class/fc_host gives me host5, host6, host7, and host8.

lsscsi shows me my drives:

```
[0:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  PLDS     DVD-ROM DS-8D3SH HD51  /dev/sr0
[2:0:32:0]   enclosu DP       BACKPLANE        1.07  -       
[2:2:0:0]    disk    DELL     PERC H700        2.10  /dev/sda
[3:0:0:0]    disk    iDRAC    LCDRIVE          0323  /dev/sdb
[4:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  iDRAC    Virtual CD       0323  /dev/sr1
[4:0:0:1]    disk    iDRAC    Virtual Floppy   0323  /dev/sdc
[5:0:0:0]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdd
[5:0:0:1]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdg
[5:0:0:2]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdi
[5:0:0:3]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdk
[5:0:0:4]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdm
[5:0:0:5]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdo
[6:0:1:0]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sde
[6:0:1:1]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdf
[6:0:1:2]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdh
[6:0:1:3]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdj
[6:0:1:4]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdl
[6:0:1:5]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdn
[7:0:1:0]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdp
[7:0:1:1]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdq
[7:0:1:2]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdr
[7:0:1:3]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sds
[7:0:1:4]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdt
[7:0:1:5]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdu
[8:0:1:0]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdv
[8:0:1:1]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdw
[8:0:1:2]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdx
[8:0:1:3]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdy
[8:0:1:4]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdz
[8:0:1:5]    disk    HITACHI  OPEN-V           5009  /dev/sdaa
```

I can fdisk to /dev/sdd, and properly create a partition.

But when I try something like mke2fs -t ext4 -m 0 -O dir_index /dev/sdd1, it tells me "/dev/sdd1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!"

Any clues?

Comment: Are you running multipath?  What does `lsblk` show?

Comment: yes.  multipath is running.  When I show an lsblk, it gives me all of the drive names (sdd, sde...), and even breaks it down to sdd1, and then shows the dm-X partitions underneath it.  Part of this problem is that I don't understand multipath well, and what it does.  So I don't quite know what I'm doing here.  But from what I see, all of the stuff in /dev/mapper shows up when I run lsblk.

Comment: Then you need to access the multipath device in /dev/mapper instead of mucking with the disk directly.